# Need clarification to stop me from exploding

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question

I have answered [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531114/use-formulas-from-other-workbooks).

Now, please scroll down to my answer. I feel that the @user is sort of *attacking* me for my approach saying that it's not what the OP wants and it's just generally completely wrong.

I do not want to jump into a further discussion in the comments section and to be honest I am starting to worry a bit if the *content of my answer is right for the question*.

Do you think I misunderstood the question and my answer is not what the OP is asking for? The only reason to explain myself in the case of misunderstanding would be the fact that English is my second language. I have read the question multiple times and IMO I think I do understand it.

I am looking forward to hear your constructive opinion (no hate) and possibly what to do next?

I have looked at the [English.Stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) but I do not think my question would have been suitable there.

Update:

I did leave it for a bit and came back today. I decided to continue the discussion based on the comments you guys have given here. A constructive exchange of opinions and supportive ideas seem to attract people and give a future user reading the answer a wider spectrum of consideration for applying the logic from the answer to his own specific case.

Comment: If you feel you are about to explode - walk away from the computer. Take a walk, do something else, calm down. Don't get dragged into it - step away and respond when you are calm.

Comment: You answer seems like an answer to the question to me. I wouldn't worry too much about what one random person on the internet thinks (he says giving you one random person on the internets opinion)

Comment: Martijn is right though, its being done the right way, convert to chat when it suggests it if the discussion may be useful, walk away otherwise

Comment: I see no hostility either - simply polite disagreement. Which is healthy - it is good to question assumptions and approaches - it is a great way to learn. People can disagree without being hostile (though this there is a cultural aspect to the response to disagreement)

Comment: Mehow, I've gotten enough of those already to just consider it part of the terrain. From what I saw I'd at least have praised a well thought out answer. Keep in mind that the other person, rightly or wrongly, sometime gets stuck feeling like they have to defend their comment juts because you didn't blindly accept it. That with the addition of talking vie asynch text, can come of as hostility, but really is not.  Glad you posted here insteadt of blowing up.

Comment: If you feel like you need to comment before walking away: Consider saying: I appreciate your feedback. I'm going to leave the answer as-is for now. I think Stack Overflow works best when everyone posts an answer and/or votes for what they think is the best solution.

Comment: Reading through those comments, ignoring your particular question here, I am thinking "Hey, that's actually quite a nice and constructive exchange of views". This is the sort of thing I would get happy about, even if I thought the opposing side was wrong/mistaken. I'd certainly not explode over it. Think of those who'd have to clean up the bloody mess.

Comment: @mehow, I've had this before where the aggrieved poster  descended into real-life stalking and threatening behaviour.  My own remedy was to sort of gently back away and diminish.  The aggrieved poster still pops up from time-to-time whenever his stalking uncovers a new opportunity to do something, but it's less frequent.  So be thankful that yours, unlike mine, hasn't taken it into the real world.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reading **just** the comments on your answer I see *no* hostility. The other user is giving you fairly constructive feedback. He doesn't agree with your approach and explains why he disagrees.

In other words, he is just stating his opinion, in a calm and reasoned manner. He's entirely entitled to that opinion. If you disagree with that opinion, then that's more than fine too.

I have not read your answer (which looks like you put a *lot* of work into it), so I cannot judge on the technical merits of yours versus the other answer. I am not familiar with Excel, really.

If you feel like you might explode, then the best answer, *always*, is to walk away and get yourself a breath of fresh air. Don't let total strangers posting on a random website on the web dictate your stress levels!

Comment: yep, and this is what I have done. I just walked away from it and to reading the comments today I dont get the upset no more.